# javascript for create tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a function in Javascript like this :

```
!function($) {

    function add_tab(num, name){

        var $newDiv = $("<div class='tab-pane' />")
                    .attr("id", "tab_"+name)
                    .html("Content " + name);
                    //.html("<div class='row'>");

        $("#graphTabsContent").append($newDiv);

        var $newLi = $("<li/>");
        if(num==0){
            $newLi.attr("class", "active");
        }
        var $newA = $("<a data-toggle='tab' />")
                    .attr("href", "#tab_"+name)
                    .html(name);
        $newLi.append($newA);
        $("#ul_tabs").append($newLi);           
    };


    function update_graph_tabs(){
        $.getJSON("call/json/get_role", {}, function(roles) {
            $("#ul_tabs").empty();
            $("#graphTabsContent").empty();

            $.each(roles, function (key, role){
                add_tab(key, role);
            });

        });         

    }

//  Run
    update_graph_tabs();

}(jQuery);
```

this function get the data from JSON and after it create  tabs tabbable, in my HTML like this(http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navs).
this is my HTML code :

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span3">
     <div class="dropdown">   
       <select class="selectpicker btn-warning" id="groupe" data-style="btn-primary">
       <option value="">Awaiting data...</option>
       </select>
     </div>
   </div>
</div> 

<div class="row">
  <div class="span4"><div id="reportingContainer"></div></div> 
    <div class="span8">
      <div id="dashboard">
        <div id="combochart"></div>
        <div id="control"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tabbable" >
    <ul id="ul_tabs"  class="nav nav-tabs">
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="graphTabsContent">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I want in every tab  it to show me one chart that I code.  For example, in my HTML O have this code that create one piechart and one combochart in my page but it is not in my tabs.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Have you attempted to solve the problem yet?  If so, it'd be good if you could provide what you've done so far, as it helps to show that you've put effort into your question, as well as helping others see where you've gone wrong and improving your code.  If you'd like to see how to write better questions, the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a good place to start.  You can find out more about Stack Overflow at the [About] page.  Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

This may help you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html lang="en">   
<head>   
<meta charset="utf-8">   
<title>Twitter Bootstrap Basic Tab Based Navigation Example</title>   
<meta name="description" content="Twitter Bootstrap Basic Tab Based Navigation Example">  
<link href="/twitter-bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap-v2/docs/assets/css/bootstrap2.2.css" rel="stylesheet">   
</head>  
<body>  
<div class="container">  
<div class="row">  
<div class="span6">  
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">  
<li class="active">  
<a href="#">Home</a> </li>   
<li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>  
<li><a href="#">Practice Editor </a></li>   
<li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>   
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>   
</ul>  
</div>  
</div>  
</div>  
</body>  
</html>  
- See more at: http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/nav-tabs-and-pills-tutorial.php#sthash.a9cP7aDC.dpuf
```

**Source:** [W3Resource](http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/nav-tabs-and-pills-tutorial.php)